# I need to minus one key, of array of objects, from another key of another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have next two arrays:

```
const firstArray = [{startDate: 5, number: 15}, {startDate: 25, number: 10}, {startDate: 26, number: 10}];
const secondArray= [{startDay: 2, endDay:10, number: 15}, {startDay: 20, endDay:30, number: 20}];
```

if `startDate` is between `startDay` and `endDay`, I have to minus firstArray `number` and secondArray `number` creating new key with result

As result, I have to put new key in firstArray with result:

```
const firstArray = [{startDate: 5, number: 15, result: 0}, {startDate: 25, number: 25, result: -10}, {startDate: 26, number: 25, result: 0}];
```

if I have more than one startDate in the same range(between startDay and endDay) I have to add to the last result of that range

The code I have for now:

```
firstArray.map(el => ({...el, result: el.number - here's number from the secondArray according to the requirements}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map won't work too well for looping through two arrays and changing values.

Just use a simple `for` loop, check your conditions between `firstArray[i]` and `secondArray[i]`, then add the value to `firstArray[i].result`

```js
const firstArray = [{startDate: 5, number: 15}, {startDate: 25, number: 20}];
const secondArray= [{startDay: 2, endDay:10, number: 10}, {startDay: 20, endDay:30, number: 20}];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(firstArray.length, secondArray.length); i++)
  if (secondArray[i].startDay < firstArray[i].startDate && firstArray[i].startDate < secondArray[i].endDay)
    firstArray[i].result = firstArray[i].number - secondArray[i].number;
    
console.log(firstArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using two or more arrays, you need to know which index you are working with. Also, for best performance, avoid any kind callback functions, use simple loops instead:

```js
const firstArray = [{startDate: 5, number: 15}, {startDate: 25, number: 10}, {startDate: 26, number: 10}];
const secondArray= [{startDay: 2, endDay:10, number: 15}, {startDay: 20, endDay:30, number: 20}];

for(let i = 0, first, second, result = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++)
{
  first = firstArray[i];
  second = secondArray[i];
  if (second && first.startDate >= second.startDay && first.startDate <= second.endDay)
    result = first.number - second.number;
  else
    result += first.number;

  first.result = result;
}

console.log(firstArray);
```

Using `map()` would work too and producing slightly shorter code, but it's slower and very unnecessary:

```js
const firstArray = [{startDate: 5, number: 15}, {startDate: 25, number: 10}, {startDate: 26, number: 10}];
const secondArray= [{startDay: 2, endDay:10, number: 15}, {startDay: 20, endDay:30, number: 20}];

firstArray.map((first, i) =>
{
  const second = secondArray[i];
  if (second && first.startDate >= second.startDay && first.startDate <= second.endDay)
    first.result = first.number - second.number;
  else
    first.result = ((firstArray[i-1]||{}).result || 0) + first.number;

});

console.log(firstArray);
```

Comment: Can it be improved because using it with next arrays couses to mistakes const firstArray = [{startDate: 5, number: 15}, {startDate: 25, number: 20}, {startDate: 26, number: 10}];
const secondArray= [{startDay: 2, endDay:10, number: 10}, {startDay: 20, endDay:30, number: 20}];

Comment: I've updated the code. We can only go by the rules you've provided in your original question. You didn't mention that the arrays could be different length.

Comment: There is no result in last object of firstArray

Comment: As I said, you didn't provide any rules, therefore I have no clue what is the expected result. Your original rule state: "if startDate of firstArray is between...." well, last item does not meet that condition, because there is nothing to compare it agains. Anyhow, you get the basics, perhaps you should figure any additional conditions yourself....

Comment: const firstArray = [{startDate: 5, number: 15, result: 0}, {startDate: 25, number: 10, result: -10}, {startDate: 26, number: 10, result: 0}];
const secondArray= [{startDay: 2, endDay:10, number: 15}, {startDay: 20, endDay:30, number: 20}];
This is result. It's like all the objects from firstArray have to plus its number if they are from the same date range ()between startDay and endDay

Comment: Please update your question with complete set of rules. I have no idea anymore what you are looking for.

Comment: last update. If you come up with another condition that doesn't work with this answer, please try come up with the solution yourself., especially if this is some school project.